# Creating a simple VUE.JS application

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to use a simple polygon cropper from Vue within an application by following the steps in this [article](https://morioh.com/p/06b7fc24c8b5).

I created my app using:

```
vue init webpack myproject
```

Now, I need to add the sample template to my app (it has a `src` folder), but I am not sure how to amend or add this piece of code to my application. The template should be as follows per the linked article:

```js
// Global
import Vue from 'vue';
import VuePolygonCropper from 'vue-polygon-cropper';
Vue.component(VuePolygonCropper);

// Local
import VueCropper from 'vue-polygon-cropper';
export default {
  components: { VueCropper}
}
```

```html
     <template>
         <div id="app">
             <polygon-crop :imageSource="'/demo.png'" ref="canvas"></polygon-crop>
             <button @click.prevent="crop">Crop</button>
             <button @click.prevent="undo">Undo</button>
             <button @click.prevent="redo">Redo</button>
             <button @click.prevent="reset">Reset</button>

         </div>
     </template>
     <script>

         export default {
             name: 'App',
             methods: {
                 crop: function () {
                     this.$refs.canvas.crop();
                 },
                 undo: function () {
                     this.$refs.canvas.undo();
                 },
                 redo: function () {
                     this.$refs.canvas.redo();
                 },
                 reset: function () {
                     this.$refs.canvas.reset();
                 }
             }
         };
     </script>
```

I am not sure what the meaning of *global* or *local* is there. My `src` folder structure is as follows:

```
 Directory of C:\ThermoAnalyser\vue_js\myproject\src

27/12/2020  11:37 AM    <DIR>          .
27/12/2020  11:37 AM    <DIR>          ..
27/12/2020  11:37 AM               374 App.vue
27/12/2020  11:37 AM    <DIR>          assets
27/12/2020  11:37 AM    <DIR>          components
27/12/2020  11:37 AM               360 main.js
27/12/2020  11:37 AM    <DIR>          router
               2 File(s)            734 bytes
               5 Dir(s)  301,183,393,792 bytes free
```

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to get this component running with just this code snippet, there's a couple of things that you would need to do to fix this up.

Before we go any deeper, I would like you to make sure if you have installed this `vue-polygon-cropper` component. If you navigated to the package.json that is located in the same level as your "src" folder, you would see a mention of vue-polygon-cropper there, if not please install it by `npm install vue-polygon-croper` .

Let's take a look at your `<template>` section first:
1- In the template, you call a component `<polygon-crop>` but, there is no component registered by that name in your script (What you are attempting to register is 'VuePolygonCropper' so you should try using `<VuePolygonCropper>` component instead.

2-I see there you copied and pasted the logo image in assets, that's a great way to test it! However, Digging through the creator's example that they put up on github, It seems like this component requires a full path to your image file instead of the relative path. so instead of /src/assets/logo.png try doing `:imageSource="require('../assets/logo.png')"`
I'm assuming the assets logo is on a folder that is one level above your current component.
So your template should look like this:

```html
<template>
<div id="app">
<VuePolygonCropper :imageSource = "require('../assets/logo.png')"
ref="canvas"> </VuePolygonCropper>
<button @click.prevent="crop"> Crop </button>
<button @click.prevent="undo"> Undo </button>
<button @click.prevent="redo"> Redo </button>
<button @click.prevent="reset"> Reset </button>

</div>
</template>
```

Now on to your script!

just import the VuePolygonCropper and mention it as a component in the components section.
You don't need to import vue and do `Vue.component(VuePolygonCropper)`. The correct way to register this component would be like this

```js
<script>
import VuePolygonCropper from 'vue-polygon-cropper';
export
default
{
    name: 'App',
    components:{VuePolygonCropper},
    methods: {
        crop: function() {
            this.$refs.canvas.crop();
},
undo: function()
{
    this.$refs.canvas.undo();
},
redo: function()
{
    this.$refs.canvas.redo();
},
reset: function()
{
    this.$refs.canvas.reset();
}
}
};
</script>
```

For the heck of it, I have created [a codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-kare-ihtqu?file=/src/App.vue) that you can play around with . You can try to play around with the App.vue file and see how it was created.

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

### "Global" vs "Local"

The "global" and "local" comments refer to [global component registration](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html#Global-Registration) and [local component registration](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html#Local-Registration). The article shows both ways of registering the `vue-polygon-cropper` component probably to make it easier to copy-paste into your own code.

#### Global component registration

You can register a component globally so that it could be used in another component without the consuming component having to register it locally. This is normally used for commonly used components that are frequently found in several components (e.g., a button).

Below is an example of global component registration that allows `MyButton` to be used in `MyForm`. Notice how `MyForm`'s `<template>` uses `MyButton` without any component registration for `MyButton` in its `<script>`.

```js
// main.js
import Vue from 'vue'
Vue.component('MyButton', { /*...*/ })
```

```html
// MyForm.vue
<template>
  <MyButton @click="onClick" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    onClick() { /*...*/ }
  }
}
</script>
```

#### Local component registration

For seldom used components (ones that are only found in a few components of your app), register the components locally instead to help minimize the bundle size if needed. If your component is never used (e.g., from a refactoring down the road), local registration allows the bundler to crop out your component from the final output.

Here's the previous example with local registration instead:

```html
// MyButton.vue
<template>
  <button />
</template>
```

```html
// MyForm.vue
<template>
  <MyButton @click="onClick" />
</template>

<script>
import MyButton from './MyButton.vue'

export default {
  components: {
    MyButton 
  },
  methods: {
    onClick() { /*...*/ }
  }
}
</script>
```

### Getting started with the sample code

To quickly get the sample code working in your project:

1. Copy the `<template>` and `<script>` parts of the sample code into your `src/App.vue`, replacing everything.
2. In the `App.vue`'s component definition, locally register `vue-polygon-cropper` as `polygon-crop`:

   ```js
   <script>
   import VuePolygonCropper from 'vue-polygon-cropper'

   export default {
     components: {
       'polygon-crop': VuePolygonCropper
     }
   }
   <script>
   ```
3. The sample code refers to an image at `/demo.png`, but your sample app only has `src/assets/logo.png`, so edit `src/App.vue`'s `<template>` so that `polygon-crop` uses `src/assets/logo.png`. We have to [`require`](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#require) the asset's path so that Webpack properly resolves the path from source:

   ```html
   <polygon-crop :imageSource="require('@/assets/logo.png')">
   ```

[sample GitHub repo](https://github.com/tony19-sandbox/vue-polygon-cropper-demo)

### Update to Vue CLI

Consider using Vue CLI's default generated templates (from [`vue create`](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/creating-a-project.html#vue-create)) instead of that outdated `webpack` template. The newly created project would still use Webpack, but most of the config for developer ergonomics are abstracted away, which can be helpful for beginners.

```
vue create myproject
```